# SQLite Foreign Key ON DELETE CASCADE(RESTRICT) across cascading tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have tables in SQLite database, that referenced by foreign keys like tree structure:

```
table1:
 id
 <other_fields>

table2:
 id
 table1_id (ON DELETE CASCADE)
 <other_fileds>

table3:
 id
 table2_id (ON DELETE CASCADE)
 <other_fields>

etc...
```

This data is received from server.
But user can store its own data in database (for example "comment" to any record).
User data is stored in additional tables, referenced, respectively, to Table1, Table2, etc.

```
table1_user_data:
 id
 table1_id (ON DELETE RESTRICT) - to forbid deleting if user data exists

table2_user_data:
 id
 table2_id (ON DELETE RESTRICT)
```

If I delete data from root table (table1) I want to preserve records that belong to "branches" with user data, others must be deleted.
But when I executing `DELETE FROM table1` - Foreign key constraint is occurred and no(!) data is removed.
But I want to remove all data that has not been referenced by user data records.

(For example, if i have only one comment(user data), referenced to one record in table2, then after delete i would like to have this comment, corresponding record in table2, and one record in table1 (on which record in table2 referenced))

What is the best way to implement this strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tell the database to delete some records, and some these records are not actually deleted (because of a constraint violation, or an error raised from a trigger, or any other reason), then the entire DELETE statement is considered to have failed, and aborted.

The only way to delete a subset of records is to add an appropriate filter to the DELETE statement itself:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id
                 FROM table1_user_data)
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id
                 FROM table2
                 WHERE id IN (SELECT table2_id
                              FROM table2_user_data))
  ... etc.
```

Alternatively, delete each record separately so that you are able to ignore constraint violation errors and can continue with the next record anyway:

```
SELECT id FROM table1;
-- for each returned id:
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 123;  -- ignore constraint errors
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 456;  -- ignore constraint errors
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 789;  -- ignore constraint errors
...
```

Comment: Yes, but record from table2_user_data can reference to table2, which is referenced to record in table1. So this record in table1 cannot be deleted. DELETE statement in your answer will be aborted too...

Comment: In this case I have to write compound query with subqueries. Besides, I have to do this for each table: table1, table2, etc. Though number of tables is about three-four, I don't think this is the best solution...
Any other ideas? I thought this problem is quite general.